# How to re compile a Java program by just editing some hard coded Key in one class file?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have a project running in Amazon AWS Lambda. It will do some automation work. We need to changes hardcoded IAM Keys in that project. We have downloaded the file from Lambda export option. Then, decompressed the project, then by using `rej_v0.7` tool I've modified the hardcoded AWS IAM code. Now I've compressed the folder as it was before and deployed it into AWS Lambda. 
But now I'm getting class not found exception for one of the class I've not touched. 
We don't have the source code of the project. We are not aware of this project Structure and dependancies etc etc., to recompile the project. Could anyone please suggest some best way to do this. 
Thanks in Advance.

Edit:
This is what I found in Manifest file
`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: .....
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_31`

Comment: Are you sure that you package everything, and the folder structure has been kept? You should make a copy of the original version of the modified jar and replace only that single class in it then give it a try. Another problem can be if the jar was signed.

Comment: what i usually do is decompile the jar, change the file and then compile the modified class using javac and setting the classpath to the original har

Comment: @m4gic @Fran Montero @amittn I've made changes to Hardcoded key only. Everything is packed as it was before. This project was developed in `Apache Ant`. Now the error is Class not found exception. is there a way to provide classpath for this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Worth checking the lambda details on the console like environment variables passed in, role assigned to it(if you are not using one its worth using a role instead of IAM keys) which subnet its deployed in and etc to make sure if you want to redeploy it you get the configurations wright.
2. All the dependencies required by that lambda have to be in the zip it self so its all that you need
3. If your zip file is small enough, you could get an inline editor to update your code on the aws console itself.
4. you could publish a new version of the lambda using aws console which will safeguard your old code on some version say x and you could change the code on the x1 version of the lambda. you would require a API gateway deployment if you are using API Gateway.

or

5. you could all together create and deploy a new lambda using the downloaded zip and copying the code on to a new lambda and try making it work using the test facility you get on aws console. and you could refer your old lambda for reference for configuration and stuff

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's quite urgent to complete the issue yesterday. So, I've updated the contents of .class files by using Byte code editor http://rejava.sourceforge.net/features.html. Later I've opened the original project's zip file in WinRAR and replaced those modified class files. And that's it, I've uploaded the zip file to Lambda and it's worked as usual.